# Planning of or on

Tags: prepositions

I am planning of reading The Perks of Being a Wall flower, this week. 
Vs 
I am planning on reading The Perks of Being a Wall flower, this week.

Which one is grammatically correct?
And if both are , then what's the difference between these two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should say "I am planning on reading..." there; "planning of" would be ungrammatical. "I plan to read..." would also be fine and mean the same thing.